# Installing third-party software in GitHub Codespaces: Eclipse IDE or CANoe?

Tags: github, codespaces, github-codespaces

I understand github codespace provide developer environment but I want to know if we can install any other specific tools also within codespace for example eclipse ide or CANoe software?
If yes please share the details on how to install.
I understand we should modify devcontainerjson file to add features and other customization and we can install extensions in vs code but I need to know if we can install third party application like I mentioned earlier which is needed for project.

Tried searching the marketplace while editing the devcontainer.json. But I didnt get any relevent information.